# How to avoid workflow firing when mocking test data

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage

I am writing a test class for a batch class and I have a scenario which I am not able to cover.

There is a formula(Number) field **Age__c** which is evaluated as `Today()-LastModifiedDate` and when **Age__c =7**,an email is sent to record owner.Also,On insertion of record,a workflow will fire and will update few fields and the object can only be accessed by two profiles(Including Sys-Admin) and workflow will fire for both the profiles.

So,in test class,I am able to insert a record with `LastModifiedDate=Date.Today()-7`.After inserting the record,workflow is firing and LastModifiedDate becomes equal to Today's date.Hence,not able to cover the scenario.

Comment: Can you try with `LastModifiedDate=Date.Today().addDays(-7)`?

Comment: @Poet Then also,After insertion,Workflow will fire and LastModifiedDate will be Today's date.

Comment: Ah sorry totally missed that part! You could try inserting a record (so they WorkflowsfFire), then updating the `LastModifiedDate`. It depends what your workflows fire off of? You'd probably want to give a bit more information on those.

Comment: Tried updating LastModifiedDate,but throws an error: System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: object.name.LastModifiedDate.

Workflow will populate a text field with logged-in user's Local Branch

Comment: Makes sense as I didn't think it would be writeable. Surprised you can set it to begin with! I think if you post your test class and exactly what your workflows are doing, it'd be a big help. :)

Comment: Hope this will help you.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181873&language=en_US[link]

Comment: Workflow will fire when record is created and if record type matches with a particular record type.Then it will update a text field with $User.LocalBranch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way than to Bypass the workflow.So,I am creating a custom setting and a custom Checkbox Field.I will modify the custom field as Post-Deployment step so that workflow will fire after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Static Resource File - TestObjectX.csv

`Name,LastModifiedDate
XForScenario1,2013-11-08T23:00:01.235-07:00
XForScenario2,<Date format Today - 7 Days>`

**Step 2:**

```
    final String staticResourceName = 'TestObjectX';
    final X[] testX= (X[]) Test.loadData(X.sObjectType, staticResourceName);
```

**Step 3:**

Now you should have X[0] with scenario 1 and X[1] with scenario 2 for testing.

*Ref:*

http://mariappanperumal.blogspot.in/2013/12/dynamic-createddatelastmodifieddate-in.html

Comment: I tried this also.It will insert a record with mentioned Lastmodifieddate.But again,on insertion,workflow will fire and update fields,hence changing the lastmodifiedDate

Comment: are you inserting the record two times ? I am little confused on "again,on insertion"

Comment: No No...Once I load the record using Test.loadData,workflow will fire.I meant that.